# How can I duplicate redis traffic from single source to multiple destinations

Tags: tcp, redis

I am working on a POC to check if we can actually duplicate redis traffic to multiple destinations coming from single host.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you mean u want to save your data on multiple redis db ? if so , you can use Replication . 
for more  info : https://redis.io/topics/replication
 and  https://redis.io/topics/sentinel-old
in these pages u will be able to create ur own Master and replica  instance

Comment: I can not use both of them for different reasons. The application we are doing the POC for does not support redis clustering (sentinel) and the replication had to be done from an instance to AWS ElastiCache which does on support SLAVEOF command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through allot of utilities and documentation. The only thing that comes close to what I wanted to achieve is

https://github.com/mudasirmirza/redis-migrate-tool

The only caveat is that, there should be enough memory to run 1 BGSAVE.